# Asyncio Autobahn behind reverse proxy rejecting connection

Tags: python-3.x, reverse-proxy, haproxy, python-asyncio, autobahn

I'm using Autobahn with Asyncio to build a lightweight socket server separate from my flask app. I have it all working but in order to route the traffic accordingly I put the two servers behind HAProxy. I am successfully getting requests to the server, but then the connection closes and server reports:

```
WebSocket connection closed: connection was closed uncleanly (port 9001 in HTTP Host header 'localhost:9001' does not match server listening port 4000)
```

So, the header does not match what the server is expecting. Is there any way to change this?

I am using Autobahn-python version 0.10.9 with Python 3.4. Here is my server code:

```
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, \
    WebSocketServerFactory
import asyncio
import json


class SimpleServer(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    def onConnect(self, request):
        print("Client connecting: {0}".format(request.peer))

    def onOpen(self):
        print("WebSocket connection open.")

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        if not isBinary:
            self.sendMessage(payload, isBinary)
        else:
            self.sendMessage(payload, isBinary)

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        print("WebSocket connection closed: {0}".format(reason))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    factory = WebSocketServerFactory(u"ws://127.0.0.1:4000", debug=False)
    factory.protocol = SimpleServer

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = loop.create_server(factory, '127.0.0.1', 4000)
    server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        server.close()
        loop.close()
```

HAProxy is version 1.4.18 and the config is:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1›  local0
    log 127.0.0.1›  local1 notice
    maxconn 4096
    user root
    group sudo                                                                                                                                                                       
    debug
    #quiet

defaults
    log  global
    mode   http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries  3
    option  redispatch
    maxconn  2000
    contimeout  5000
    clitimeout  50000
    srvtimeout  50000

frontend public
  bind *:9001
  acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
  use_backend ws if is_websocket
  default_backend www 

backend www 
  timeout server 30s 
  server www1 127.0.0.1:3000

backend ws
  timeout server 600s
  server ws1 127.0.0.1:4000
```

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Ok for anyone stuck on this, it was fixed by changing

```
factory = WebSocketServerFactory(u"ws://127.0.0.1:4000", debug=False)
```

to:

```
factory = WebSocketServerFactory()
```

Apparently, specifying the url in the Factory will cause Autobahn to run checks on the headers.